# Reading data from invisible cell of NatTable in a test

Tags: junit

I want to develop testcases and APIs for testing of a variety of nattables. I'm stuck up to read data from invisible cells of nattable. 
Here are my requirements:

1. The testing codebase does not have dircet access to Layer objects. I have to get them through nattable.getLayer() or similar api given by NatTable.class. I can also use other static things like LayerUtil.
2. I cannot assume any particular layer stack because the testing APIs need to be used for various nattables. The layer stack can be different in these nattables.
   So I guess I cannot type-cast nattable.getLayer() to any specific layer.
3. The number of rows used for row/column headers can be different. There can be cases in which column/row headers will be absent. If they are present then also they can be of different number of rows/columns. e.g. some nattables can have 1 row for column header and some can consume 3 rows and so on.
   Is there something by which I can know- which row number contain first data element?

I use NatTable's getRowCount() and getPreferredRowCount() to determine whether the given cell position is visible or not.

I am trying to use ShowCellInViewportCommand so that it will enable me to read data from invisible cells by making them visible. But as I cannot assume any definite stack structure, how should I make a call to ShowCellInViewportCommand successful?
e.g.

`natTable.doCommand(new ShowCellInViewportCommand(natTable.getLayer(), 10, 40));`

Here suppose 20 rows are visible and row 40 is invisible but it is valid cell. 
Nothing happens in the UI.
Is any single API going to work in this generic scenario? Do I need to write a set of APIs for different configurations? But there can be many such combinations.

I also thought of using PAGE_UP, PAGE_DOWN, UP, DOWN keystrokes and getting the cell visible instead of using NatTable APIs. But for it, I need to click on some cell initially. I am afraid that there can be key bindings on some nattables.

How should I proceed? Please suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the variety of configurations, transformations and abstractions in NatTable, there is no simple generic solution for testing. You need to make assumptions on the layer stack to be able to test. For example, if there is no `SelectionLayer` involved, how could you test the selection behavior? You are already making an assumption with your statement that calling `NatTable#getRowCount()` returns only the number of visible rows, which is only true in case a `ViewportLayer` is involved in the layer stack.

So the first thing to realize is that you have to implement some code to verify your assumptions. Like in NatTable configurations itself, you could do this by inspecting labels. For the questions above this would be some code that checks if the underlying layer of the NatTable itself is of type CompositeLayer, and in that case it should check the region labels for `GridRegion#BODY`. If you have found a layer stack with that region label, you have found the layer that shows the content. At least it is recommended to use the region label `GridRegion#BODY` for that. If someone misses this because of customization, it will also fail.

Regarding your concrete question for making an "invisible cell visible", which technically means to trigger scrolling for moving a cell in the viewport. The `ShowCellInViewportCommand` is handled by the `ShowCellInViewportCommandHandler` which is registered to the `ViewportLayer`. If that is all in place, it should work. If you try to make a row visible that doesn't exist (mind the index-position transformation) nothing will happen.

That means I suppose row index 40 is the last row in your example, and therefore the index might not be correct. As Java uses 0-index-based collections you need to use row index 39.